# How can I copy files to my ipod using Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox

I don't want to sync my Apple Brand product with RhythmBox, I just want to be able to drag and drop MP3s, similar to the way you might apply files to a USB drive. This has in the past worked without failure, does anyone know why it might have stopped working? Do I need to tell you my iPod version, or what release of Ubuntu I'm on?

Comment: Please add details about your iPod, your Ubuntu and your Rhythmbox version :)

Comment: The question I left is not what you can read and I'm not about get into another role back war.

Comment: Yes please give as much information as possible, your ipod version and model as well as your ubuntu version.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Rhythmbox 3.3 and an old IPod nano
In my case I just copy from existing playlist in Rhythmbox and paste in IPod device it have it's own icon in Rhythmbox so the process is as follows:

1. Create new playlist if not have any with desired files
2. Select all the files that need to be transferred to the IPod
3. Copy files
4. Select IPod name in Rhythmbox
5. Paste the files.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, infact didn't even need to create a playlist, just selected tracks from my Music lib (on computer) in Rhythmbox, chose "copy", then clicked on ipod nano under Devices in Rhythmboxes lefthand side window and pressed ctrl-v as for soem reason right-click on the ipod entry under devices didn't show a context menu to do the paste.

Answer (score 0):

@tomwrong,
In my opinion you don't have to sync IPod with Rhythmbox. This is the same as Manual Sync, where you sync only if you want to.

I am not aware if you can drag and drop to IPod without linking it to some software. My knowledge dictates that ITunes was meant to do the role and since then other players have offered an easier and better route to do the same.

I believe RB, banshee and other players only recognise the IPod and do not participate in implanting any imprints into the IPod player.

In Manual Control in RhythmBox, you are essentially dragging and dropping. 
This may not be the exact answer but if not you, will help others who come along seeking information.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Under ubuntu 10.04, in rhythmbox you can select your music files, drag them to the ipod icon on the left side panel and thus to copy the files in the ipod.

With an another computer running ubuntu 12.10, I try to do the same but it doesn't work no more!! What seems to be possible is to SYNCHRONIZE. I bet that  files in the ipod, but not in the computer will be erazed.

Does that mean that rhythmbox behaves like itune, I guess yes!

Comment: Sad fact, both versions are old..