# Ubuntu and Ipods 2014

Tags: music, ipod

I have an ipod shuffle and I want to copy mp3 into it.

How hard is it to do on Ubuntu ? I tried Amarok, Rhytmbox, nothing works.

Any help?

Comment: Why 2014 in the title?

Comment: Have you looked at any of these http://askubuntu.com/questions/994/can-i-sync-with-my-ios4-device-such-as-iphone-4-and-ipad and http://askubuntu.com/questions/160325/how-can-i-copy-files-to-my-ipod-using-rhythmbox

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ifuse` to mount your ipod.

Install it using `sudo apt-get install ifuse`.

From `man ifuse`

`ifuse - Mount filesystem of an iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad or Apple TV.`

```
This  mounts  the  root filesystem of the first attached device on this
   computer in the directory /media/iPhone.
```