# How to connect iPad to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ipad

How can I connect an iPad to Ubuntu 16.04?

I can't seem to find a way to do so. I searched but I only found posts about using wine or dual booting Windows alongside Ubuntu. Also these articles are outdated and talk of the ancient 12.10 or 10.04.

Is there a package I can use to do this on Ubuntu without cursing myself for breaking up with Windows for good?

Basically I want to transfer files to and from the Linux machine to the iPad.

Comment: http://tunesviewer.sourceforge.net/ios-transfer-made-easier/

Comment: hi thanks, i tried your recommendation, isnt there something native to linux to do this?

Comment: No, there isn't, You can contact Apple and ask why.

Comment: haha..i would but they wouldn't listen. thanks anyway :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu and Ipods 2014](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517906/ubuntu-and-ipods-2014)

Answer (score -1):

Just go to apple store and download documents 6, and plug in your Ipad.
That is all you need to do.

I tried running various commands (without understanding them) without success.

Pinguy didn't work for me either.

Comment: documents 6? could you elaborate?

Comment: Go the the appstore on your ipad and search for "documents 6" and download it. Attach your ipad to your pc and a little television icon appears on the launcher. That is it.